# Laravel - Array Strings and Texts does not store in my database

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am new to laravel so please guide me, My problem is, I need to store a string and text array in my database in laravel, tho I cannot pass anything inside the database using arrays.. can anyone help me out here please thanks.

Here is my code in View and Controller

> My code in View

```
   {!! Form::open(['action'=>'Admin\AboutusController@store', 'method' => 'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'name' => 'add_name', 'id' => 'add_name']) !!}
<div class="form-group">   
    <div class="table-responsive">  
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
           <tr>  
              <td>  {{Form::text('title[]', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Title'])}}<br>
                    {{Form::textarea('description[]', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Description'])}} <br>

                          {{ Form::file('about_image[]') }}


              </td>
              <td>{{ Form::button('', ['class' => 'btn btn-success fa fa-plus-circle', 'id'=>'add','name'=>'add', 'style'=>'font-size:15px;']) }}</td>
           </tr>  
        </table>  
        {{Form::submit('submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'name'=>'submit'])}}
    </div> 
</div>  
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

There you can see my textbox, textarea and submit button

> My Controller

```
 $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'about_image' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($request->has('about_image'))
    {   
        //Handle File Upload

        $about = [];
        foreach ($request->file('about_image') as $key => $file)
        {
            // Get FileName
            $filenameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get just extension
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Filename to Store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $file->storeAs('public/about_images',$fileNameToStore);
            array_push($about, $fileNameToStore);
        }

        $fileNameToStore = serialize($about);
    }
    else
    {
        $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
    }

    foreach ($about as $key => $value) {
    $aboutContent = new About;
    $aboutContent->title = $value->input('title');
    $aboutContent->description = $value->input('description');
    $aboutContent->about_image = $value;
    $aboutContent->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get information that is not available from the $about array.

try replacing it with:

```
foreach ($about as $key => $value) {
    $aboutContent = new About;
    $aboutContent->title = $request->title[$key];
    $aboutContent->description = $request->description[$key];
    $aboutContent->about_image = $value;
    $aboutContent->save();
}
```

You might just want to make sure that the title and description line up with the correct image

Comment: You welcome Summer. We all start in the same place. when you are having trouble in the future you can use Log::info({variable}) and then you can see the data that you are trying to access in your log file